# adapt container width and make it resizeable

Tags: css, html

I want to create a contrainer with source code in it. The problem I have now is that the `width` of my container gets to big, and I dont know how to change that.

Here is the **HTML-file** I am try to use ...

```css
body {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: DarkGray;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: LightGray;
}

header {
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 6em;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 0;
}

article {
 display: block;
 margin:.5em 0;
 background: white;
 padding:.5em 1em;
 min-height:21em;
}

fieldset {
 border-radius: .4em;
 border-style: groove;
 border-color: blue;
 color: blue;
 /* display: inline-block; */
 /*max-width: 75em;*/
 padding: 0 1em; 
 /*position: relative;*/
 /*width: 100%;*/
}

div {
 /*position: relative;*/
 max-width: 75em;
}

code {
 color: black;
}

header, article {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.div_content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    
    <html>
     
    <head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>HTML & CSS Examples</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/example.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <header>
     <h1>HTML & CSS Examples</h1>
    </header>
    
    
    <article>
    
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    
     <fieldset><legend>HTML</legend>
     <div class="div_content">
    
    <pre><code>&lt;header&gt;
     &lt;h1&gt;HTML Examples&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;/header&gt;
    
    &lt;article&gt;
    
     &lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.&lt;/p&gt;
    
    &lt;/article&gt;
     
    </code></pre>
    
     </div>
     </fieldset>
    
    </article>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried a few things but without success, as you can see in my **css-file**...

```
body {
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: DarkGray;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: LightGray;
}

header {
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
}

article {
    display: block;
    margin:.5em 0;
    background: white;
    padding:.5em 1em;
    min-height:21em;
}

fieldset {
    border-radius: .4em;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: blue;
    color: blue;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /*max-width: 75em;*/
    padding: 0 1em; 
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
div {
/*position: relative;*/
max-width: 75em;
}
code {
    color: black;
}

header, article {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.div_content {
/*max-width: 75em;*/
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

most success I had with `max-width: 75em;` but in fullscreen modus only and my container isnt resizeable still.

when executing this html file you will see the container and its sourrounding fieldset. Both are bigger than the article it self. How to fix this ?

I want this container always to be inside the article, even when I switch size of the browser.

Comment: If you create a fiddle or code snippet, It will be easy to help you.

Comment: never done this before, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thank you. Please see my answer. I think it helps.

Comment: still the same behavior., sorry your answer didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set up the width with vw (viewwidth) value instead em. This will make resizable... and if you can set a limit to this width, just put max-width: 100%; for respect the maximum parent width.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about the `<code>` tag the has different behaviors.

The best thing I can suggest you is using this:

```
 code{
   display: inline-block;
   over-flow: scroll;
   width: 90%;
 }
```

It makes a limited width for your code element, But I think there is no way to wrap its lines.?? So you can make this scrollable.